# Why does changing the order of tables in the FROM clause of Oracle cause errors when trying to do a JOIN

Tags: oracle

If these statements can be represented by `SELECT a FROM x,y JOIN z ON y.id = z.id WHERE ...` Changing the order of x and y will either work, or cause an error. Below are the two full queries and the exact error being produced in SQL Developer

---

### Example 1:

(snippet)`FROM (SELECT ...), persons prsn LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum ON psum.prsn_id prsn.prsn_id`

```
SELECT prsn.prsn_id, person_points.points, psum.psum_points_available
  FROM (SELECT prsn_id prsn_id, sum(points) points
          FROM (SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       invoices inv,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       orders ord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id     = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.inv_id      = inv.inv_id
                   AND inv.ord_id       = ord.ord_id
                   AND ord.prsn_id_byr  = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       reward_order_details rdet,
                       reward_orders rord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND rdet.rdet_id     = pnts.rdet_id
                   AND rord.rord_id     = rdet.rord_id
                   AND rord.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       miscellaneous_points misp,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND pnts.mpts_id     = misp.mpts_id
                   AND misp.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       returns rtn,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id    = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.rtn_id     = rtn.rtn_id
                   AND rtn.prsn_id_byr = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id)
        GROUP BY prsn_id) person_points,
        persons prsn
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum on psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  WHERE person_points.points > 0
    AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
    AND ((NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM point_summaries x
                        WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

Returns a successful table:

```
| prsn_id | points | psum_points_available |
|------------------------------------------|
| 111111  | 676    | 287                   |
| 111112  | 11672  | 1971                  |
| 111113  | 137    | 89                    |
| 111114  | 156    | (null)                |
| 111115  | 5111   | 570                   |
| 111116  | 280    | (null)                |
```

### Example 2:

(snippet)
`FROM persons prsn, (SELECT ...) LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum ON psum.prsn_id prsn.prsn_id`

```
SELECT prsn.prsn_id, person_points.points, psum.psum_points_available
  FROM (SELECT prsn_id prsn_id, sum(points) points
          FROM persons prsn,
               (SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       invoices inv,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       orders ord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id     = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.inv_id      = inv.inv_id
                   AND inv.ord_id       = ord.ord_id
                   AND ord.prsn_id_byr  = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       reward_order_details rdet,
                       reward_orders rord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND rdet.rdet_id     = pnts.rdet_id
                   AND rord.rord_id     = rdet.rord_id
                   AND rord.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       miscellaneous_points misp,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND pnts.mpts_id     = misp.mpts_id
                   AND misp.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       returns rtn,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id    = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.rtn_id     = rtn.rtn_id
                   AND rtn.prsn_id_byr = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id)
        GROUP BY prsn_id) person_points
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum on psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  WHERE person_points.points > 0
    AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
    AND ((NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM point_summaries x
                        WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

Returns the error:

```
ORA-00904: "PRSN"."PRSN_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 49 Column: 16
```

I have been looking around for an answer but everything I find seems to say that the order of the `FROM` should not matter. Does it start to matter if you are using a `SELECT` subquery to generate a temporary table in the `FROM` clause of your query? Or perhaps there is there something else going on here that I am missing that someone could enlighten me on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you want to mix the old and new syntax? ('New' in the loosest sense, of course, as it's 27 years old...) Even when it works it's confusing at best, and as you can see, fragile.

Comment: SQL is not my strongest language. I am taking queries from a Legacy Codebase and altering them to achieve my end goal. The Oracle database I am querying against is over 19 years old. I am asking this question to understand what is 'Legacy' and what would be a better way to achieve this without using something so fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the subquery, or the left join. The problem is that you're mixing implicit and explicit join syntax.

As a much-simplified example:

```
select *
from dual a, dual b join dual c on c.dummy = b.dummy
where b.dummy = a.dummy;

D D D
- - -
X X X

select *
from dual b, dual a join dual c on c.dummy = b.dummy
where b.dummy = a.dummy;

ORA-00904: "B"."DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

The explicit `JOIN` syntax is taking precedence of the implicit join from the comma-separated table list in the `FROM`; so the first query is effectively doing:

```
select *
from dual b
join dual c on c.dummy = b.dummy
join dual a on b.dummy = a.dummy;

D D D
- - -
X X X
```

while the second is effectively doing:

```
select *
from dual a
join dual c on c.dummy = b.dummy
join dual b on b.dummy = a.dummy;

ORA-00904: "B"."DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

With that syntax it's more obvious that at the first point you reference `b.dummy`, the `b` table alias has not yet been defined, hence the error.

It isn't a good idea to mix the two join styles. I'd suggest you standardise on the 'new' explicit join syntax:

```
FROM (SELECT ...) person_points
JOIN persons prsn ON prsn.prsn_id = person_points.prsn_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum ON psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
```

or

```
FROM persons prsn
JOIN (SELECT ...) person_points ON person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum ON psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
```